# Hosting a static website containing JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-hosting

I have customized a free downloaded web template as my simple, static website. It contains HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/jQuery.

I want to make it live, and am confused from where to host it. The hosting providers say that as my site contains JavaScript/jQuery it will have to be hosted on a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), which is very costly. I don’t want to spend this much money.

Is it necessary to host on a VPS?

Comment: I don't think this is the right site of the network where to ask this sort of question, but anyway hosting on a VPS is not necessary. Basically, any old dirt cheap shared web hosting will do. You just need to copy your static assets to the root of the website and you're golden.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between *hosting* static `.js` files that are served to clients, and *running* a JS program *on the server* to generates dynamic files in response to requests.

The services you are looking at seem to be charging more for the latter. If you only need the former, any static hosting will do, as @[s.m](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/14409/s-m)'s comment points out.